# Cannot install odt for visual studio 2017. Installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I wanted to install odt for visual studio 2017. I downloaded the installer from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html. The installer starts and after some time, an error pops up saying that the tools couldn't be installed, and it tells me to look in a log file it generated and remove the error, but i can't seem to find what the error is in the log file. The content of the log file is as follows:

```
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - -------------------------------------------
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - 15.0.26228.9 built by: D15RTWSVC
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - -------------------------------------------
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - Command line parameters:
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual         Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\ide\vsixinstaller,/skuName:Enterprise,/skuVersion:15.0,/quiet,/admin,C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\odt\Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0.vsix,/logFile:C:\Users\maaz\AppData\Local\Temp\Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0_vsix_7-24-2019_14-33-47.log
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - -------------------------------------------
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - -------------------------------------------
24/07/2019 2:33:48 PM - Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio     18\Common7\IDE\ssms.exe: Unable to find an entry point named '?' in DLL     'PkgdefMgmt.dll'.
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - Initializing Install...
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - Extension Details...
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Identifier         : Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Name               : Oracle Developer Tools for     Visual Studio 2017
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Author             : Oracle Corporation
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Version            : 18.3.0
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Description        : Oracle Developer Tools for     Visual Studio 2017 is a free VS addin that makes it easy to browse and modify     Oracle schema objects and data, edit and debug PL/SQL, generate SQL deployment scripts, perform schema comparisons, tune SQL and .NET app performance, and much     more.
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Locale             : en-US
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     MoreInfoURL        :     http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-    097110.html
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     InstalledByMSI     : False
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.5,)
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     SignatureState     : Unsigned
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Supported Products : 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -             Version : [15.0]
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -             Version : [15.0]
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -             Version : [15.0]
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     References         : 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Prerequisites      : 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         --------------------------------------------    -----------
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Identifier   :     Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Name         : Visual Studio core editor
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -         Version      : [15.0,16.0)
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - 
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - Signature Details...
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM -     Extension is not signed.
24/07/2019 2:33:49 PM - 
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Looking for master PkgDef file,     Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\master.pkgdef

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Creating PkgDefCacheNonVolatile
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Double-checking master pkgdef     file
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement initialized
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: RootFolder, Path: C:\Program     Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: ShellFolder, Path: C:\Program     Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefSearchPath, Path:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.admin.pkgdef

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: ImageManifestSearchPath, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions;C:\Users\maaz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ae723756\Extensions

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: ApplicationExtensionsFolder, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: "ZeroImpact" = dword:0, "MergeRegistry" = dword:3
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: User extensions enabled by setting, Path: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_ae723756\ExtensionManager\EnableAdminExtensions

24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefCache flags, PKGDEF: 7001
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: Could not find ConfigurationChanged timestamp., PKGDEF: 80070002
24/07/2019 2:33:51 PM - PKGDEF Information: PkgDefManagement startup complete
24/07/2019 2:33:52 PM - The extension with ID 'Oracle.VsDevTools.15.0' is not installed to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017.
24/07/2019 2:33:52 PM - Beginning to install extension to Visual Studio Enterprise 2017...
24/07/2019 2:33:52 PM - Install Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException:     Unable to find the specified file.
   at     Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.GetInstanceForSetupI    nstance(ISetupInstance2 currentSetupInstance, ServiceProvider     setupServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.Install(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InstallSilently(IInstallableExtension extension, IReadOnlyList`1 installSKUs)
24/07/2019 2:33:52 PM - VSIX TaskScheduler: VSIX Auto Updatetask already     exists.
24/07/2019 2:33:52 PM - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.GetInstanceForSetupInstance(ISetupInstance2 currentSetupInstance, ServiceProvider setupServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.PerformSetupEngineInstall(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, Boolean installPerMachine, Boolean isPackComponent, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, IProgress`1 progress, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IInstalledExtension& newExtension)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.InstallInternal(InstallableExtensionImpl extension, InstallFlags installFlags, IDictionary`2 extensionsInstalledSoFar, List`1 extensionsUninstalledSoFar, IInstalledExtensionList modifiedInstalledExtensionsList, AsyncOperation asyncOp, IProgress`1 progress)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BeginInstall(IInstallableExtension installableExtension, InstallFlags installFlags, AsyncOperation asyncOp)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.Install(IInstallableExtension extension, InstallFlags installFlags)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.InstallSilently(IInstallableExtension extension, IReadOnlyList`1 installSKUs)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
```

I've downloaded the most recent version of odt for visual studio 2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the most recent version of Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017.

You might be using the most recent copy of the add-on, but you are not running the current version of Visual Studio 2017, since the issue you are running into was fixed in `Visual Studio 2017 15.3.2`.  Once you upgrade to `Visual Studio 2017 15.9.14` you should be able to install the add-on without a problem.

> This issue has been fixed and is now available in our latest update. You can download the update via the in-product notification or from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/ Thanks to everyone who provided feedback.

Source: [Failed to initialize settings for Isolated Shell C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/52828/failed-to-initialize-settings-for-isolated-shell-c.html)

> Visual Studio upgrade fails with AccessDenied failure during VSIX install / uninstall.

Source: [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3.2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.3#visual-studio-2017-version-1532)